# MYSQL How to GROUP BY date

Tags: mysql

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-05 08:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2023-06-05 13:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 2023-06-06 08:00:00.000 |
| 4 | null |
| 5 | 2023-06-05 08:00:00.000 |
| 6 | null |

[RESULT]

I want to group by date where date is **null** or **not null**

| count(date) | date |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | NOT_NULL_DATA (string value) |
| 2 | NULL_DATA (string value) |

Comment: This is simple conditional aggregation, you forgot to include your current attempt with an explanation of what is not working.

Comment: Does "NOT_NULL_DATA" mean a valid date? or the value "NOT_NULL_DATA" please [edit] your question and show your attempt and elaborate your question.

Comment: i edited it. it means just value. @JoSSte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Stu in comments, This can be done using the conditional aggregation :

```
select  count(*), case when date is not null then 'NOT_NULL_DATA' else 'NULL_DATA' end as date
from mytable
group by case when date is not null then 'NOT_NULL_DATA' else 'NULL_DATA' end
```

Or simply :

```
select  count(*), case when date is not null then 'NOT_NULL_DATA' else 'NULL_DATA' end as date
from mytable
group by 2
```

However, using order by / group by ordinal is something to avoid

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mx9Rm2JK)

Comment: In MySQL there is no need to repeat the complete expression after `GROUP BY`. It can be replaced by the column number (`2` in this case).

Comment: It is possible, but I have read somewhere that it is bad habit to use group by / order by ordinal https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86609/why-do-we-use-group-by-1-and-group-by-1-2-3-in-sql-query

Comment: True, but it's still possible... 

Comment: That is True :)